# GraphQL dynamic groupsField not working if type of group is list

Tags: javascript, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I am trying to create a project for internal employees to give permission based on groupsField.

I have referred the AWS documentation for dynamic permission, but it's not working in my case.

Here's relevant part of graphql schema

```
type something
@auth(
  rules: [

             { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }
             { allow: groups, groupsField: "groupRead", operations: [read] }
             { allow: public }



]
)
  @model
  @searchable
{
  id: ID!
  phone: String
  email: String
  groupRead: [String!]

}
```

If I try to search the result from my front-end side and in AppSync,  it's not allowing me search anything and give back empty array of items.

Two errors:

1. Not authorized to access the list
2. gives back empty result

But if I change to

groupRead: String!

Then it works for front-end as well as in AppSync. But In this case, for dynamoDB I can not assign more than one value to groupRead. As an admin I want to give them more than one department read permission.

All static group permissions are working perfectly fine, for instance Admin.

**Goal: groupRead should be type of list, so in DynamoDB I can pass multiple value to groupRead.**

Comment: Good feature request. Until then, you can add the authorization code on the mutation code: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authorization-use-cases.html